# Ricoh YF-20 film loading issue

Tags: film, ricoh

I recently purchased a second-hand Ricoh YF-20. I loaded the film as best I could, shut the back door and loaded the 2 AA batteries. Immediately, a load motor sound came from the camera and the film did not begin to wind up.

I'm wondering if this is an issue with the motor, the film loading mechanism or something else.

I looked at the user manual and I couldn't find anything to help with this issue. I'm also wondering if I can fix this by myself or if I will need to bring it in to have it serviced. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will be looking at $125+ for a technician to deduce the problem and fix the camera if you cannot fix it yourself. When you buy second hand, **always** do a function test before buying. If you can't return this, then by all means, attempt to fix it yourself. However, you could buy the camera ~2-3 times over for the cost of a single repair. Consequently, if it is broken or you break it...just go find another - repairs for these aren't worth it (outside of sentimental value, if that is ever the case).

Answer (score 1):

On this camera the film does not auto advance to the first frame when you shut the back cover. Once the film is  in you then have to use the shutter release button repeatedly to advance it until the frame counter reads 1.

[Here is  link](https://www.central-manuals.com/instructions_manual_user_guide_camera/ricoh.php) to a page that has a link on it, at the bottom of the page, to download a PFD of the manual.

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZuDme8d_5Q)  It is in a foreign language but it shows the film loading process.

I know you said you looked at the user manual so i am not sure how you missed the instructions on loading the film.

**A note for all who buy used cameras.**

- *All of this information was easily obtained by using the internet to search for Ricoh YF-20 manual. Whenever you buy a used camera **the first thing you should do** is search the internet for the manual and **read it carefully**.*

[image]

[image]